# Dynamically insert HTML after page load (and change after key press)

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, document-ready

When my page loads, content is pulled from a database with PHP and populated within numerous Bootstrap `.col-xs-3` columns, all within a single `.row`.

However, I need to close off the `.row` and start a new one every four columns **using JavaScript/jQuery** after the page has loaded and also on `keyup`, inserting the relevant HTML to the code where it needs to go. This is because the amount of content on the page can change dynamically depending on user input within a search bar (which hides certain columns).

The HTML structure of my page is as follows:

```
<input id="search" type="text">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">6</div>
</div>
```

Whereas I need it like so:

```
<input id="search" type="text">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">6</div>
</div>
```

However, I cannot hard code the new rows with PHP, because user input in the search bar might change the visible page content to the following, and I need the rows to close in the correct places dynamically (note how `4` is missing):

```
<input id="search" type="text">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">5</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">6</div>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery right now, but it does not seem to be working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function rowBreak() {
        var columnCount = 0;
        $('col-flex:visible').each(function() {
            columnCount++;
            if (columnCount % 4 == 0) {
                $(this).append('</div><div class="row">');
            }
        });
    }
    rowBreak();
    $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
        rowBreak();
    });
});
```

EDIT: And I've just realised, my code does not even take in to account the removal of additional rows before re-adding them in the correct places each key press...

Comment: first, you forget "." in class selector "col-flex"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is based on the fix of the following line:

```
$(this).append('</div><div class="row">');
```

This line should be:

```
var nextEles = $('.col-flex:hidden:gt(' + index + ')');
$('<div class="row">').append(nextEles).insertAfter(this.closest('div.row'));
```

Mainly, your variable columnCount  is not usefull. Take a look to [each parameters](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

My snippet:

```js
function rowBreak() {
  $('.col-flex:hidden').each(function (i, e) {
    if (((i + 1) % 4 == 0) && ($(this).siblings().length != 3)) {
      var x = $('.col-flex:visible:gt(' + i + ')');
      $('<div class="row row-temp">').append(x).insertAfter($(this).closest('div.row'));
    }
  });
}

$(function () {
  rowBreak();
  $('#search').on('keyup', function () {
    $('.col-flex').hide();
    var s = this.value.toLowerCase();
    $('.col-flex').filter(function () {
      return $(this).find('h4').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(s) > -1;
    }).show();
    rowBreak();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search...">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">AECLIM</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">AEMET</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">AME</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">APMG</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">ATCN</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">METEOMET</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">MMC 2016</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">SATCOM 2016</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great for `(document).ready()`, thanks. However, it only adds rows, meaning when using the search bar, more and more rows get added, but none ever get removed! I tried using `$('.col-flex).unwrap()` to remove all the rows before re-adding them, but this doesn't work...

Comment: @mpdc You are right. I forgot the correct test: if (((index + 1) % 4 == 0) && ($(this).siblings().length != 3)) {  Let me know if you continue to have problems. Thanks so much

Comment: Could you please take a look at my JSFiddle, and see what is going wrong when this is implemented with the searching functionality? https://jsfiddle.net/n69b49v3/ For instance, search `MET` and see that the rows do not form correctly.

Comment: And this is it updated with my `unwrap()` attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/n69b49v3/1/ (try the same search for `MET`)

Comment: @mpdc Snippet updated with the code from your jsfiddle. Because in your  keyup event handler you hide the elements the search must be for hidden elements, .... I hope this will solve your problem. Could you accept and upvote?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to implement it like this. may this helps you.

Visit this [codepen link](http://codepen.io/uzess/pen/pbppQp).

HTML:

```
<div class="row hidden">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">7</div>

</div>
Out put here
<div id="output"></div>
```

JS:

```
function abc(){   var count = 0;   var output = '';
    $( '.col-flex' ).each(function(){
        if( count % 4 == 0 ){
          output += '<div class="row">';
        }

      count++;
      output += '<div class="col-xs-3 col-flex">';
      output += $(this).text();
      output += '</div>';
      if( count % 4 == 0 ){
          output +='</div>';
        }
    });
    if( count % 4 !== 0 ){
        output +='</div>';
    }
     return output; } $( document ).ready( function(){   $('#output').append( abc() ); });
```

Comment: add some sample code here. This reference link may get updated in future.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct an object from the PHP to hold your data and and build all the markup on load:

HTML

```
<input id="hidden_myPHPdata" type="hidden">
<div id="markupHolder"></div>
```

PHP - Array of data

```
// Construct at server and send to a hidden field
var data = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12], ...];
```

Javascript

```
// You data
var dataSet = $('#hidden_myPHPdata').val();
dataSet = JSON.parse(dataSet);

// Place all your markup in a predefined element
var markupHolder = document.getElementById('markupHolder');

for(var item in dataSet) {

   // Create row div
   var row = document.createElement('div');
   row.className = 'row';

   // Loop through the columns
   for (var col in dataSet[item]) {
     var col = document.createElement('div');
     col.className = 'col-xs-3 col-flex';
     col.innerHTML = dataSet[item][col];
     row.appendChild(col);
   }

   // Append row to markup holder
   markupHolder .appendChild(row);

}
```